# DirectX - Writing to 3D Texture Causing Display Driver Failure

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I'm testing writing to 2D and 3D textures in compute shaders, outputting a gradient noise texture consisting of 32 bit floats. Writing to a 2D texture works fine, but writing to a 3D texture isn't. Are there additional considerations that need to be made when creating a 3D texture when compared to a 2D texture?

Code of how I'm defining the 3D texture below:

```
HRESULT BaseComputeShader::CreateTexture3D(UINT width, UINT height, UINT depth, DXGI_FORMAT format, ID3D11Texture3D** texture)
{

D3D11_TEXTURE3D_DESC textureDesc;
ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));
textureDesc.Width = width;
textureDesc.Height = height;
textureDesc.Depth = depth;
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.Format = format;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

return renderer->CreateTexture3D(&textureDesc, 0, texture);

}

HRESULT BaseComputeShader::CreateTexture3DUAV(UINT depth, DXGI_FORMAT format, ID3D11Texture3D** texture, ID3D11UnorderedAccessView** unorderedAccessView)
{

D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uavDesc;
ZeroMemory(&uavDesc, sizeof(uavDesc));
uavDesc.Format = format;
uavDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE3D;
uavDesc.Texture3D.MipSlice = 0;
uavDesc.Texture3D.FirstWSlice = 0;
uavDesc.Texture3D.WSize = depth;

return renderer->CreateUnorderedAccessView(*texture, &uavDesc, unorderedAccessView);

}

HRESULT BaseComputeShader::CreateTexture3DSRV(DXGI_FORMAT format, ID3D11Texture3D** texture, ID3D11ShaderResourceView** shaderResourceView)
{

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;
ZeroMemory(&srvDesc, sizeof(srvDesc));
srvDesc.Format = format;
srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE3D;
srvDesc.Texture3D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
srvDesc.Texture3D.MipLevels = 1;

return renderer->CreateShaderResourceView(*texture, &srvDesc, shaderResourceView);

}
```

And how I'm writing to it in the compute shader:

```
// The texture we're writing to
RWTexture3D<float> outputTexture : register(u0);

[numthreads(8, 8, 8)]
void main(uint3 DTid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{

float noiseValue = 0.0f;
float value = 0.0f;
float localAmplitude = amplitude;
float localFrequency = frequency;

// Loop for the number of octaves, running the noise function as many times as desired (8 is usually sufficient)
for (int k = 0; k < octaves; k++)
{

    noiseValue = noise(float3(DTid.x * localFrequency, DTid.y * localFrequency, DTid.z * localFrequency)) * localAmplitude;

    value += noiseValue;

    // Calculate a new amplitude based on the input persistence/gain value
    // amplitudeLoop will get smaller as the number of layers (i.e. k) increases
    localAmplitude *= persistence;
    // Calculate a new frequency based on a lacunarity value of 2.0
    // This gives us 2^k as the frequency
    // i.e. Frequency at k = 4 will be f * 2^4 as we have looped 4 times
    localFrequency *= 2.0f;

}

// Output value to 2D index in the texture provided by thread indexing
outputTexture[DTid.xyz] = value;

}
```

And finally, how I'm running the shader:

```
// Set the shader
deviceContext->CSSetShader(computeShader, nullptr, 0);
// Set the shader's buffers and views
deviceContext->CSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cBuffer);
deviceContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, &textureUAV, nullptr);

// Launch the shader
deviceContext->Dispatch(512, 512, 512);

// Reset the shader now we're done
deviceContext->CSSetShader(nullptr, nullptr, 0);

// Reset the shader views
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* ppUAViewnullptr[1] = { nullptr };
deviceContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, ppUAViewnullptr, nullptr);

// Create the shader resource view for access in other shaders
HRESULT result = CreateTexture3DSRV(DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, &texture, &textureSRV);
if (result != S_OK)
{

    MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to create texture SRV after compute shader execution", L"Failed", MB_OK);
    exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, simple mistake. Compute shader threads are limited in number. In the compute shader you're limited to a total of 1024 threads, and the dispatch call cannot dispatch more than 65535 thread groups. The HLSL compiler will catch the former issue, but the Visual C++ compiler will not catch the latter issue.

Comment: You should try the [Direct3D Debug Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/) which will emit warnings/errors at runtime for these kinds of CPU-side programming errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a texture of 512 * 512 * 512 (which seems what you are trying to achieve), your dispatch needs to be divided by groups:

```
deviceContext->Dispatch(512 / 8, 512 / 8, 512 / 8);
```

In your previous case, the dispatch was :
512*8 * 512*8 * 512*8 = 68719476736 units

Which very likely triggered the time out detection and crashes the driver

Also the limit of 65535 is per dimension, so in your case you are completely safe to run this.

And last one, you can create both shader resource view and unordered view right after creating your 3d texture (before the dispatch call).

This is generally recommended to avoid mixing context code and resource creation code.

On resource creation, your check is not valid either :

```
if (result != S_OK)
```

HRESULT success condition is >= 0

you can use the built in macro instead eg :

```
if (SUCCEEDED(result))
```